# Can you save an edit to a SEDE query's title or description without editing the query?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I don't create queries in SEDE much but when I do, I forget to give them a useful title and description until after I'm finished creating them and click the permalink button.

In an effort to avoid adding yet another query with a less-than-useful title and description (or in my case an incorrect one), I click "edit" under the query and adjust the title and add a description.

Yay!... but... wait... there's no new "permalink" button and there's no save button next to the title or description sections... or anywhere for that matter.

So... how do I save my nice new description if I don't have any edits to make?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can, although it's somewhat unintuitive.

Tl;dr do Run Query and then you'll get the permalink button again.

---

Long answer:

1. Do <kbd>edit query</kbd>, as you did.
2. Modify the description/title as desired.
3. Do <kbd>Run Query</kbd> - this is required for permalink to appear. Not sure why, but it seems like it is.
4. Now, you'll get the <kbd>permalink</kbd> button again